# how can i resolve windows crash error

Tags: c#, winforms

My application creates an exe in the client application folder and tries to run it from there. Even though the exe runs properly and functionality is not disturbed, I get a crash popup with below details in it. The same stuff works in in our development & test machines without crash popups.

Only thing I managed to find out to temporarily fix this situation was to set the registry entry as below

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting DontShowUI =1
```

Now I am clueless of what could be causing this exception as the only hint is `more.dll` which I found in the error details and this is not something that I added as reference in my project. Is there a better way to programmatically resolve this issue or can someone please help me with more ideas on this.

```
    Problem signature:

          Problem Event Name:                        APPCRASH
          Application Name:                             MNM_Interface.exe
          Application Version:                           1.0.0.0
          Application Timestamp:                     54eaf32a
          Fault Module Name:                          more.dll
          Fault Module Version:                        1.2.1.0
          Fault Module Timestamp:                  54e2d422
          Exception Code:                                  c0000005
          Exception Offset:                                0040bb62
          OS Version:                                          6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
          Locale ID:                                             1033
          Additional Information 1:                  0a9e
          Additional Information 2:                  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
          Additional Information 3:                  0a9e
          Additional Information 4:                  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789


Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

I have no idea if below event viewer logs will help but something which i thought the experts can get a clue .

```
Faulting application name: MNM_Interface.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5523d05b
Faulting module name: more.dll, version: 1.2.1.0, time stamp: 0x54e2d422
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0040bb62
Faulting process id: 0x1870
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0713b195e7b30
Faulting application path: C:\MNM\Pictures 1.1.0\MNM_Interface.exe
Faulting module path: C:\MNM\Pictures 1.1.0\more.dll
Report Id: 586ce056-dd2e-11e4-b2ce-08edb9de061e
```

Comment: The Windows Error Reporting popup is the default behavior if an unhandled exception occurs in a windows application.  To get a stack trace for debugging, handle the [AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

Comment: I have a question here. should i handle unhandledException in parent application that calls the exe or rather handle them in the called exe  ?

Comment: AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain; currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(DomainExceptionHandler); Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);     I tried the above. I changed my exe to include logs from starting of program.cs main method till the end. All the logs were properly written . No exceptions were caught in catch block nor there was an App Domain exception or thread exception . So basically i couldn't stop this crash popup from coming. Any Help guys ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use some resources, like icons, bitmaps, dll or other type, which program use, but at the moment they are not available?
If yes - try to remove them and look how program will behaves.

Comment: didn't find something like that

Answer (score 0):

As @BJMyers mentioned, it is an unhandled exception. You can write an external program to test/handle the exception. You can have something like:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionFunction;

private void UnhandledExceptionFunction(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception ex = (Exception)(args.ExceptionObject);
    System.Diagnostics.StackFrame frame = new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(0);
    string method;
    method = frame.GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName;
}
```

A good way to start would be to look at the `args` parameter to get the `ExceptionType`. If you want to get more detail, e.g the method that caused the exception, you can take a look at the `StackFrame` class

Comment: Thanks for the response but really sorry for the delay in my response. Well does it mean that i need to handle this unhandled exception event in my program.cs for the exe . The reason i ask is it does already have a try catch block and am kind of confused how come it doesn't get caught there.

Comment: Yes you can handle it in your `Program .cs`. Well, even if it does have a `try catch block`, you can't have assurance that the exception is caught. You may have written a catch block for `NullPointerException` when in fact it threw a `DivideByZeroException`, something like that. Also, there are instances when exceptions occur in configuration files where the exception is thrown even before a `try-catch block` is executed. If you already know the exception, you can try catching it in the `try-catch block` you have written. As I mentioned, you can use the above code to get the exception type.

Comment: In current scenario i was not handling a specific exception in the catch block as it was only try {}catch(){} and expected the catch block to handle any exception that is coming inside the try block . Now if i go and add AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionFunction, i believe this should be in program.cs in static void main function . am i rite ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and see if the exception is caught inside your catch block?

Comment: Hi jmc, well i have put the below code in the program.cs  and gonna test it in the client machine soon.  AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(DomainExceptionHandler);
            Application.ThreadException +=
            new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

Comment: Ok . So i was able to replicate the issue in a virtual machine and got the same event viewer logs. I changed my exe to include logs from starting of program.cs main method till the end. All the logs were properly written . No exceptions were caught in catch block nor there was an  App Domain exception or thread exception . So basically i couldn't stop this crash popup from coming. Any Help guys ?

Comment: Well that's quite odd, does your application by any chance run an external program?

Comment: My application is doing process.start() to call an external exe to get some data. Also the external exe is present in another product folder.  I did more debugging to find that the external exe is  executing properly till the end of main method and before the control passes to my main application i get the crash popup . The event viewer logs as given before shows that it has got something to with more.dll in the product folder. Exception Code:  0xc0000005

Comment: I have tried to handle the thread exception in both Parent exe and child exe. However it fails to do so for this issue.Any other way to programmatically handle this issue ?