# exe has stopped working. How can this be handled programmatically?

Tags: c#, dll, process, exe, windows-error-reporting

My c# application is using `Process.start()` to call another exe internally and after that it calls `process.waitforexit()`. I am getting a popup with below message after the child exe is fully executed

> MNM_Interface has stopped working
>
> A Problem Caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

My logs show that there is no exception in my parent exe or child exe. However the error popup is coming only after full execution of code inside child exe. 
Eventviewer shows an Exception code: `0xc0000005`.

```
Faulting application name: MNM_Interface.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5523d05b
Faulting module name: more.dll, version: 1.2.1.0, time stamp: 0x54e2d422
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0040bb62
Faulting process id: 0x1870
Faulting application start time: 0x01d0713b195e7b30
Faulting application path: C:\MNM\Pictures 1.1.0\MNM_Interface.exe
Faulting module path: C:\MNM\Pictures 1.1.0\more.dll
Report Id: 586ce056-dd2e-11e4-b2ce-08edb9de061e
```

I tried using below code in both parent and child exe but couldn't prevent this popup from coming.

```
AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;   
currentDomain.UnhandledException += new   
    UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(DomainExceptionHandler); 
Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

Well the solution I got after checking various sources was to set below registry entry and it works well.

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
>   DontShowUI =1

However i have no clue how to programmatically prevent this error from coming in the application. Is it possible by any means ?

I am attaching the code used to call the child exe.

```
try
        {

            if (dllPath.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()))
            {
                dllPath = dllPath.Remove(dllPath.Length - 1, 1);
            }
            System.Diagnostics.Process pr = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            pr.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            pr.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(strExe);
            pr.StartInfo.FileName = Path.GetFileName(strExe);
            pr.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            pr.StartInfo.Arguments =
                " " + strAct + " "
                + "\"" + dllPath + "\" "
                + "\"" + strProject + "\" "
                + "\"" + strUser + "\" "
                + "\"" + strPassword + "\" "
                + "\"" + strDb + "\" "
                + "\"" + strXml + "\" "
                + strModule;
            pr.Start();
            MessageBox.Show("Before process execution");
            pr.WaitForExit();
            MessageBox.Show("After process execution");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

Some more Info:
Faulting module name: more.dll .
If i try to open this dll with ildasm.exe i get no valid CLR header and can't be disassembled. So i guess i should focus on how to handle unmanaged code exceptions thrown by an externall dll from my CLR based c# application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i resolve windows crash error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665380/how-can-i-resolve-windows-crash-error)

Comment: Can you post all the code to creating the child process? It may be an issue if you are redirecting standard input or standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an access violation, and assuming you don't have faulty ram, you could try a third party exception logger such as from:
www.eurekalog.com or madexcept.com

See also a similar response at:
stackoverflow.com/questions/14949904/what-do-i-do-when-my-program-crashes-with-exception-0xc0000005-at-address-0

It is also possible if your more.dll is written in C you have an uninitialized pointer.

Another possibility is Windows is raising a Data Execution Prevention (DEP) error trying to access protected memory

Comment: Since more.dll is not in my control & is being referenced internally by some other dll, is there any possibility that i can prevent this popup from coming by writing code in child exe or parent exe ? I am not sure how we could do it as this popup comes after execution of finally block in the child exe code.

Comment: Here is what i could do .  1) Turned off DEP but the same exception is there. 2) i don't know how to find if its a faulty ram ? 3) if more.dll is having an uninitialized pointer , how can i still work on getting this issue resolved ?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to add an unsafe { } block around whatever code uses the more.dll. You will also have to go to Project > Properties > Build and check "Allow unsafe code". This may or may not help. Not having access to the more.dll code really limits your options at this point.